# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/framework/create' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angularjs, express

i have an error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/framework/create' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

how i fix it?

i'm use angular v7 and express.js for backend

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({providedIn : 'root'})
export class CommonService {

  uri = 'http://localhost:3000/framework';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  addFramework(framework, bahasa) {
    const obj = {
      framework: framework,
      bahasa: bahasa
    };
    console.log(obj);
    this.http.post(`${this.uri}/create`, obj)
        .subscribe(res => console.log('Done'));
  }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are using chrome, just go to 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi
and intall it. refresh the page and it should work.

Comment: how if i'm using firefox?